# Atomic increment does not work as expected in interrupt

Tags: c++, multithreading, embedded, atomic

I have a Google Coral Dev Micro with a RT1176 SoC (800MHz Cortex-m7 and 400MHz Cortex-m4) the m7 is running FreeRTOS and the m4 is running bare-metal, compiling using GCC none eabi 9.3.1 with the following flags:

```
-Wall -Wno-psabi -mthumb -fno-common -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mapcs-frame --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -u _printf_float -std=gnu99 -g -Os -save-temps -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -DNDEBUG
```

I want to communicate data generated in a timer interrupt between the two cores using shared memory and I have created my own lock-less FIFO buffer in shared memory:

fifo.h:

```
#include <array>
#include <atomic>
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>

template <typename T, size_t num_elements>
class LockLessFifo {
   public:
    LockLessFifo() : read_idx(0), write_idx(0), buffer({0}) {}

    size_t size() {
        if (read_idx <= write_idx) {
            return write_idx - read_idx;
        } else {
            return num_elements - (read_idx - write_idx);
        }
    }

    constexpr std::size_t capacity() { return buffer.max_size(); }

    void put(const T& entry) {
        // Wait for space
        while ((num_elements - size()) < 2) {
            ;
        }

        size_t new_write_idx = (write_idx + 1) % num_elements;
        buffer[new_write_idx] = entry;

        // Update the write index AFTER writing the data
        write_idx = new_write_idx;
    }

    T get(const bool block = true) {

        if (!block && size() == 0)
            return -1;
        
        while (size() == 0) {
            ;
        }

        // Consume
        size_t new_read_idx = (read_idx + 1) % num_elements;
        T retrieved_value = buffer[new_read_idx];

        // Update the read index AFTER reading (to signal availability to the producer)
        read_idx = new_read_idx;
        return retrieved_value;
    }

   private:
    std::atomic<std::size_t> read_idx;
    std::atomic<std::size_t> write_idx;
    std::array<std::atomic<T>, num_elements> buffer;
};
```

shared_fifo.h

```
#include "fifo.h"

using shared_element_t = uint32_t;
constexpr std::size_t SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE = 0x1700;  // Manually calculated free space using map file
constexpr std::size_t SHARED_MEMORY_ELEMENTS = SHARED_MEMORY_SIZE / sizeof(shared_element_t);
LockLessFifo<shared_element_t, SHARED_MEMORY_ELEMENTS> shared_fifo __attribute__((section(".noinit.$rpmsg_sh_mem")));
```

I don't expect the FIFO code to be perfect, but it is functional. I have only shared it out of completion and to give all context.

The FIFO is read from the m7 as follows:
main_m7.cpp

```
#include <cstdio>

#include "libs/base/ipc_m7.h"

#include "shared_fifo.h"

extern "C" [[noreturn]] void app_main(void* param) {
    (void)param;

    coralmicro::IpcM7::GetSingleton()->StartM4();
    uint32_t counter1, counter2;
    while (true) {
        counter1 = shared_fifo.get();  // Works
        counter2 = shared_fifo.get();  // Always 0
        
        const std::size_t fifo_size = shared_fifo.size();
        constexpr std::size_t fifo_capacity = shared_fifo.capacity();
        
        printf("[M7] counter: %lu/%lu size: %u/%u\r\n", counter1, counter2, fifo_size, fifo_capacity);
    }
}
```

The FIFO is filled on  the m4 as follows:

main_m4.cpp

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

#include "fsl_pit.h"

#include "shared_fifo.h"


static std::atomic<std::size_t> counter1 = 0;
static std::atomic<std::size_t> counter2 = 0;

void my_pit_irq() {
    // Clear IRQ flag
    PIT_ClearStatusFlags(PIT1, kPIT_Chnl_0, kPIT_TimerFlag);
    
    counter1.store(counter1.load() + 1);  // Works
    counter2.fetch_add(1);                // Always 0

    SDK_ISR_EXIT_BARRIER;
}


extern "C" [[noreturn]] void app_main(void* param) {
    (void)param;

    configure_and_start_timer(); // removed for clarity

    while (true) {
        shared_fifo.put(counter1.load());   // Works
        shared_fifo.put(counter2.load());   // Always 0
    }
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
(...)    
[M7] counter: 71666076/0 size: 1470/1472
[M7] counter: 71666076/0 size: 1470/1472
[M7] counter: 71666077/0 size: 1470/1472
[M7] counter: 71666077/0 size: 1470/1472
[M7] counter: 71666077/0 size: 1470/1472
(...)
```

Why does the incorrect increment (counter1) work, but the correct increment (counter2) not? I've taken a look at the disassembly:

The PIT interrupt:

```
_Z10my_pit_irqv:
    
    // Clear IRQ flag
    ldr r3, .L3
    movs r2, #1
    str r2, [r3, #268]

    ldr r2, .L3+4      // Load .LANCHOR0
    dmb ish
    ldr r3, [r2]       // Load value stored at address of .LANCHOR0 (.load())
    dmb ish
    adds r3, r3, #1    //  Increment by 1
    dmb ish
    str r3, [r2]       // Store incremented value (.store())
    

    ldr r3, .L3+8      // Load .LANCHOR1
    dmb ish            
    dmb ish            // Dubble barrier?
.L2:
    ldrex r2, [r3]      // load 
    adds r2, r2, #1     // increment
    strex r1, r2, [r3]  // store
    cmp r1, #0          // check
    bne .L2             // retry

    dmb ish
    dsb 0xF

    bx lr             
.L4:
    .align  2
.L3:
    .word   1074626560
    .word   .LANCHOR0  // counter1
    .word   .LANCHOR1  // counter2
```

And the main:

```
app_main:
    push {r0, r1, r2, lr}
    ldr r6, .L14            // Counter1
    ldr r4, .L14+4
    ldr r5, .L14+8          // Counter2
.L13:

    // This is the same as for counter2
    add r1, sp, #4
    ldr r3, [r6]            // Load the value of counter1
    dmb ish
    mov r0, r4
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    bl  _ZN5LockLessFifoImLj1472EE3putERKm  // Put it in the FIFO
    dmb ish

    // This is the same as for counter1
    add r1, sp, #4
    ldr r3, [r5]            // Load the value of counter2
    dmb ish
    mov r0, r4
    str r3, [sp, #4]
    bl _ZN5LockLessFifoImLj1472EE3putERKm  // Put it in the FIFO
    b .L13
.L15:
    .align  2
.L14:
    .word   .LANCHOR0
    .word   _ZN511shared_fifoE
    .word   .LANCHOR1
```

I don't see where it is going wrong. I know the FIFO is functional, since the increment is working and we see the number printed in the terminal going up. The generated assembly is very similar and looks correct to me. Unfortunately, I cannot connect a debugger (yet) since I would need to solder the JTAG header to the board, and we need to wait before making any modifications.

Thanks for taking the time to take a look.

Comment: Usually you use `ldrex/strex` for atomicity with respect to other cores sharing a coherent L1 cache, and it operates via the MESI protocol.  Does your system document that it gives you atomicity with respect to the other CPU?  I suppose that would require it to take a bus lock or something like that.  If you do a test where you simply have both CPUs concurrently do atomic increment of the same variable, do you get correct results?

Comment: Also, is `dmb ish` the right barrier?  The inner-shareable domain is, again, usually cores sharing the L1 cache, and in particular they would normally all be running the same OS.  I wonder if your other core is actually in the inner-shareable domain.  If not then `dmb ish` may not flush caches back far enough to achieve global visibility.

Comment: @NateEldredge good points, the shared memory is in OCRAM. The read/write indexes are updated correctly, however, these are only updated from one side. When I have time I will add a shared counter and see if it's incremented correctly.

The `dmb ish` barrier is inserted by the compiler, do you know how I can instruct the compiler to generate more agressive dmb instructions?

Comment: I doubt that you can, except by hacking the compiler.  I don't think gcc really supports the use of atomics for anything except multithreading, which would be multiple homogeneous cores in the inner-shareable domain.  You may have to fall back to using `volatile` for your loads and stores, and inserting barriers manually, e.g. `asm("dmb osh" : : : "memory");`

Comment: @NateEldredge I just had some time to test this. I've added a shared atomic counter and let both cores increment it 1000000 times. The resulting count did not equal 2000000.

Thanks for the assistance, I'll awnser my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help of @NateEldredge in the comments I've found the answer: C++ atomics do not compile correctly on this hardware platform. The compiler generates `dbm ish` instructions, which only synchronize the inner shareable domain.

I've verified this by incrementing a shared counter 1000000 times on each core, and the result did not equal 2000000.

This could possibly by fixed by manually replacing the `dbm ish` with `dbm osh` instructions, but a quick and dirty fix was not sufficient:

```
// the attempt that didn't work
for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    asm("dmb osh" : : : "memory");
    unica::shared_fifo.shared_counter++;  // not actually atomic wrt. other core
    asm("dmb osh" : : : "memory");
}
```

Unfortunately, I'll just drop using the `std::atomic`s and go back to using `volatile`s and masking IRQ where necessary

---

Update after a discussion on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/embedded/comments/1bv1hqw/comment/kxz7yz8/?context=3

It seems like the memory region was configured as not shareable. I will test if this is the issue if I have time.

Comment: Makes sense; barriers don't create atomicity, they can only help with ordering (and perhaps visibility between caches which aren't coherent.)  So it seems LDREX / STREX isn't failing when the other core modifies that cache line; it presumably also only works on inner-shareable.

Comment: Disabling interrupts only gives atomicity on a single-core system.  If the other core could be modifying a variable, `x.store(x.load() + 1)` won't be atomic, and that's how `volatile` compiles.  And disabling interrupts even on both cores won't help.  Unless the only code on the other core that modifies the shared variable is inside an interrupt handler, and you leave interrupts disabled for long enough that if it was in that handler already, it will have finished the increment before you do your increment.